# Python: How to print the stacktrace of an exception object without a "currently being handled" exception?

Tags: python, exception

How can I print the stacktrace of an exception object such as the return value of `concurrent.futures.Future.exception()` ?  Most of the `traceback` and `sys` exception functions depend upon an implicit exception that is "currently being handled" (this includes `sys.exc_info`, `traceback.print_exc`, `traceback.format_exc`).  The exception has already been handled, and is returned as an object, so these are worthless to me.  There are a couple of `traceback` functions which take an exception argument, but they either give no stack trace output, or they require a traceback object as input, which I do not have.  I could of course create a traceback object, but that object would not contain the information I need.

Yes, I am aware that there are lots of Q/A here about printing the stacktrace of an exception.  I've searched through them.  This question is completely distinct from those.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for idx in range(0, 10):
        future = executor.submit(third_party_script.main)
        threads.append(future)

for future in threads:
    if(future.exception()):
        print(magic_traceback_function(future.exception()))
```

How can I print the stacktrace of an exception object such as the return value of `concurrent.futures.Future.exception()` ?

Comment: My understanding is that you can get the exception to raise by calling `future.result()`. As far as I know, it should contain the original traceback, too. So, you could catch the exception by putting `future.result()` in a try block and print the traceback.  Let me know if that works. There's also the `__traceback__` attribute which may be helpful for you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Thank you.  It turns out that the most useful way to get an exception from a future is by using `Future.result()`, not `Future.exception()`.  I did read the documentation for `Future.result()`, but the awkward wording ("If the call raised, this method will raise") didn't make sense to me.  @sytech, you should post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the exception to raise by calling `future.result()`. As far as I know, it should contain the original traceback, too. So, you could catch the exception by putting `future.result()` in a try block and print the traceback. There's also the `__traceback__` attribute which may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [`exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.exception) method which returns the exception raised by the call. So, you can get the traceback from it as from any other exception (**Python 3.5+**). Use [`traceback.TracebackException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#tracebackexception-objects) for it (just replace `ex` with your exception):

```py
print("".join(traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(ex).format())
```

An extended example and other features to do this:

```py
import traceback

try:
    1/0
except Exception as ex:
    print("".join(traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(ex).format()) == traceback.format_exc() == "".join(traceback.format_exception(type(ex), ex, ex.__traceback__)))
    print("".join(traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(ex).format()))
```

The output will be something like:

```py
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untidsfsdfsdftled.py", line 29, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this until I discovered that with [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) you can actually use the `@logger.catch` annotation to see the exception logs/stacktrace (and actually in a colorful way!), like so:

```py
@logger.catch
def other_script():
    ...

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for idx in range(0, 10):
        executor.submit(other_script)
```

However, it might not help if you can't annotate the third party script. In any case, it helped me.